# Prove $\int_X g\,d\phi=\int_X gf\,d\mu,$ when $\phi(E)\triangleq \int_Ef\,d\mu$ for any measurable set $E$ in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I was reading Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.  I can understand that if $\phi(E)\triangleq \int_Ef\,d\mu$ then $\phi$ is a measure.  However, I'm not so sure how to prove $\int_X g\,d\phi=\int_X gf\,d\mu.$  ($f,g:X\to[0, \infty]$ are measurable functions, and $\mu$ is a measure.)  I list my attempted proof below, and would appreciate it if someone can confirm if it's correct, or point out where I'm mistaken, or give a simpler proof.

---

**My proof:**  Since $g$ is measurable, there exists a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of increasing simple measurable functions on $X$ that converge to $g$, i.e. $0\le s_1\le s_2 \le \cdots$ and $s_n \to g.$  So, by Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT), $\int_X s_n\,d\phi \to \int_X g\,d\phi.$

Suppose $s_n=\sum_i\alpha_i\chi_{E_i},$ where $\chi_{E_i}$ is the characteristic function of $E_i$.  Then we have 
$$\int_X s_n\,d\phi=\sum_i\alpha_i \phi(E_i) = \sum_i\alpha_i \int_{E_i}f\,d\mu=\sum_i\alpha_i \int_X\chi_{E_i}f\,d\mu=\int_X\sum_i\alpha_i\chi_{E_i}f\,d\mu,$$
where the last term is simply $\int_Xs_nf\,d\mu$.  Since $\{s_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and $f$ is non-negative, clearly $\{s_nf\}$ is also increasing.  Therefore, by MCT again, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X s_nf\,d\mu=\int_X\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n f \right)\,d\mu=\int_Xgf\,d\mu,$$
which concludes the proof.

---

Is this correct?  Can it be simplified or improved?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no need to write \underset{n\to\infty}\lim. In a displayed context, just write \lim_{n\to\infty} and you see this: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ In an inline context you see $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ but you can also code it as \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} and then you see $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}. \qquad$